# How to start an activity when clicking a notification inside that activity

Tags: android, notifications

I am developing a game.I am using notification service in my game.I created this notification and it works perfectly fine when I am in a different Activity.Also when I close the game and click a received notification it redirect to the correct Activity(GameScreen.class).But when I am inside the GameScreen Activity and if I receive notification the GameScreen does not updae with received values.It remains as the same.I tried many solutions.My notification is as follows

```
private void newBamRecieve(String msg,String id) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Preparing send notification...: " + msg);
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivityIntentService.this, GameScreen.class);

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

              intent.putExtra("InentID", a);


    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);             
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
            .setContentTitle("MY Notification")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg);

    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    Notification build = builder.getNotification();
    build.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
    build.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    Random random = new Random();
    int m = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;
    mNotificationManager.notify(m, build);
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification sent successfully.");

}
```

This is a part of my Gamescreen Activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_screen);



int i = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("InentID");

}
```

I have another two buttons in this activity.Wha I want to do is reStarting this Activity with my new data from the notification while I'm inside this Gamescreen activity.When I'm in another activity my code works fine.Please help me.I think there should be something to do with Intent falg values.But I don't know how

Comment: what does your gamescreen activity (especially the part where changes should happen) look like?

Comment: show your gamescreen activity

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.I need to start Gamescreen activity when click the notification when I am in the GameScreen activity.When I am not in that activity it start GameScreen activity and get all data.Help me.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use this code snippet

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 

getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        "A new notification", System.currentTimeMillis());
// Hide the notification after its selected
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

Intent intent = new Intent(this, NoficationDemoActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("buzz", "buzz");
intent.putExtras(bundle);
PendingIntent activity = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "This is the title",
        "This is the text", activity);
notification.number += 1;
notificationManager.notify(0, notification
```

hope so will works for you:)

Comment: @chithi what is happening there.please let me know:)

Comment: I need to start the Gamescreen activity with clicking notification when I am already inside that activity.If I 'm outside that Activity this works fine(that means the Gamescreen activity starts)